# I am getting error while defining H2OContext in python spark script

Tags: python, apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water, h2o.ai

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pysparkling import *

hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate()
```

I am using spark standalone cluster 3.2.1 and try to initiate H2OContext in python file. while trying to run the script using spark-submit, i am getting following error:

> ```
> hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate() NameError: name 'H2OContext' is not defined
> ```

Spark-submit command:

> spark-submit --master spark://local:7077 --packages
> ai.h2o:sparkling-water-package_2.12:3.36.1.3-1-3.2 spark_h20/h2o.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `--packages ai.h2o:sparkling-water-package_2.12:3.36.1.3-1-3.2` downloads a jar artifact from Maven. This artifact could be used only for Scala/Java. I see there is a mistake in [Sparkling Water documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.2/latest-stable/doc/tutorials/use_as_spark_package.html).

If you want to use Python API, you need to:

- Download SW zip archive from [this location](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/spark-3.2/3.36.1.3-1-3.2/index.html)
- Unzip the archive and go to the unzipped folder
- Use the command `spark-submit --master spark://local:7077 --py-files py/h2o_pysparkling_3.2-3.36.1.3-1-3.2.zip spark_h20/h2o.py` for submitting the script to the cluster.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying this from 2 days and couldnt understand the problem. Also, The main problem was naming my python script "h2o.py" as this was causing the problem.